# Scrapy commands not working inside project directory

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have set environment variable to `python27/Scripts`. I am able to create project by

```
Scrapy startproject fund
```

So a project fund is created. Now I go inside the directory of fund where configure file is present and here scrapy is not recognised. Say I want to generate a spider or crawl it it does not work? Please advise on how to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are working with Anaconda, but if you are, than you might have to activate the virtual environment.

open: Anaconda prompt

Write: activate [insert name of your virtual environment]

cd to the place where you want to start your project (so for example cd desktop)

write: scrapy startproject [NameOfYourProject]